# Call custom tool from TFS build

Tags: deployment, msbuild, continuous-integration, workflow

We are using TFS2010 for our web sites's builds and we're in the process of creating fully automated builds. At the moment the sites are built and deployed in remote servers.

The sites contains several configuration files that we would like to transform as part of the build. As there are some rules to create the correct config files we would like to use a custom tool for that purpose (.exe), not to use xml transformations for it.

From what we can see in the build template, MSBuild copies the files to a drop folder and then pushes them to the remote IIS site. We would like to hook our custom tool to this process and do the transformations in the build server before the site is published. The problem is that the MSBuild task is a single node in the build template and we can't find a place where to invoke our tool. Before the MSBuild step, there is no code deployed to the drop folder, after the MSBuild step the code was already deployed to the remote server.

Any ideas on how to plug the custom tool in the correct workflow step?

Answer (score 0):

What is the msbuild target, that you use? I think you can define your own target in csproj file to do the following:

1. execute your custom tool against required files
2. run usual build target (or whatever target you normally use)

**Edit**
E.g. in a .csproj file you could define the following:

```
<Target Name="buildWithCustomTool">

    <!-- Exec your custom tool -->
   <Exec Command="your command" />   
    <!-- Call the build target which will run as normally -->        
   <CallTarget Targets="Build" />

</Target>
```

Hope it helps,

Ivan

Comment: Just to add to Isantipov's response.  You basically need to create a command line tool, since the build-machine will have no gui-interaction.  This is how things like nunit.x.x.x.exe work.  Even "custom msbuild tasks" are often nice property setting wrappers for some command line tool.  If your .exe cannot be used as a command line, you may have to build a custom msbuild task and use the libraries (if any) your custom .exe exposes.